# Printing the values of all tdms files in the same directory using the for loop in python

Tags: python

I have a folder abc where I store my tdms files and I extract the data from those files using the the following function in  python, now the problem is each time I run my main program I need to change the file number in the main so that I can run it, What I would like to do is that making changes into the load function and it will keep loop in same directory and print different values of files, lets say in abc I have file1.tdms, file2.tdms,... each time it should be printing values of  different file in that folder abc

```
class loader():
    def load(self, path):

        
        tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(path)
        df = tdms_file.as_dataframe()
        file_read = TdmsFile.read(path)
        data = file_read.groups()[0].channels()[0].data
        
        plt.suptitle('Timeseries data', fontsize='30')
        plt.xlabel('Timestamp', fontsize ='20')
        plt.ylabel('feature values', fontsize='20')
        plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0])
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python package called glob. It is is used to return all file paths that match a specific pattern.

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('src/*.tdms')
['src/file1.tdms', 'src/file2.tdms', 'src/file3.tdms', ...]
```

You will get a list of all file names and then you can loop through them one at a time.